# Nginx: route to index.php within alias for specific path component

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to make nginx route to the index.php within an alias for a specific path. It would be easier to just use subdomains (and add serverblocks with different names), but my project requires this structure for several non-topical reasons. Simply put, I would like the following:

```
1. www.example.com         --> /home/user/www/public/index.php
2. www.example.com/a/b     --> /home/user/www/public/index.php
3. www.example.com/api     --> /home/user/api/public/index.php
4. www.example.com/api/a/b --> /home/user/api/public/index.php
```

Numbers 1 and 2 are pretty standard: always serve the index.php file (in a certain root) and let php take care of the routing. Number 3 simulates a subdomain construction (and should point to index.php in a different directory).

I've managed to get numbers 1-3 to work, but not number 4. Whenever I go to www.example.com/api/a/b it gives a 404. The error logs tell me nginx is trying to serve me /home/user/api/public//a/b/. I feel like I'm pretty close to the solution, but I don't seem to get it right. I would also be able to serve static files in the same manner.

The following configurations are relevant:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    root /home/user/www/public;

    index index.php index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri /index.php =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_index   index.php;
            fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            include         fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    } 
    location /api {
        alias /home/user/api/public/;

        location ~ \.php$ {
           try_files $uri /index.php =404;
           fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
           fastcgi_index   index.php;
           fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
           include         fastcgi_params;
           fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
         }
    }      
}
```

Thanks in advance.

**Solution**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    root /home/user/www/public;

    index index.php index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri /index.php =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_index   index.php;
            fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            include         fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    } 
    location /api/ {
        alias /home/user/api/public/;
        try_files $uri /api/index.php =404;

        location ~ \.php$ {
           try_files $uri /index.php =404;
           fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
           fastcgi_index   index.php;
           fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
           include         fastcgi_params;
           fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
         }
    }      
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're pretty close. But you need to match the trailing `/` characters for `location` and its corresponding `alias`.

You also need to add a `try_files` in that block to refer to the correct `index.php`, which is probably `/api/index.php`.

```
    location /api/ {
        alias /home/user/api/public/;
        try_files $uri /api/index.php;
```

Comment: Oops. Forgot to anonymize it... :( (edited it) Thanks for the help. Trying it now.

Comment: This removes the double slash, but nginx is not routing it to index.php. It is giving me a 404.

Comment: You need to fix your `try_files`. It should point to the _correct_ `index.php`, which is probably going to be `/api/index.php`.

Comment: I edited my try_files in the php location block in the alias to "try_files $uri /api/index.php =404;" and it is now serving 404 pages (without it showing up in the nginx error logs). This is also the case when going to /api/.

Comment: I'll try some other things, I feel like I'm really close. Why is nginx not throwing a 404 error in the logs, but is returning the 404 page? Also, could you edit your answer to match the (edited) question? Thanks.

Comment: I solved it by adding "try_files $uri $uri/ /api/index.php;" to the location /api/ block. And leaving "try_files $uri /index.php =404;" in the php block inside the /api/ block. I will accept your answer and edit my question. Could you edit your answer to match the correct directory? Thanks a lot!